# lapply Malfunction When Converting S4's to List to Dataframe

Tags: r, database, for-loop, lapply

I'm scraping PubMed for bibliographic data using the package RISmed and having a heck of a time with lapply.  My general goal is to go from a single search in RISmed to a dataframe in R.

Problem 1: There's a return max of 99,999, which I hit very quickly. To solve this, I've broken up the search.

Problem 2: Lapply has been malfunctioning, which I think happens when the search returns "zero" but I'm not sure. Here is the error code:

```
 list_cpg <- lapply(search_cpg[1:length_issn], gen_df)
 Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'PMID': invalid class “EUtilsSummary” object: invalid object for slot "PMID" in class "EUtilsSummary": got class "list", should be or extend class "character"
```

I've pared down the code to make it simpler (the actual code is ~1800 searches, but you hit it within the 15 iterations below). I've tried using paste functions to reduce duplicate values, tried a bunch of failed for loops, attempted to cut searches that return zero (but it's variable from study type to study type), etc.

In short, here are the functions for using RISmed that gets you all the way to that error

```
install.packages("RISmed") 
library(RISmed)


### Function to scrape Pubmed into S4  

scrape_pubmed <- function (x) {
  x %>%
    EUtilsSummary(
      retmax=99999, 
      datetype = "ppdt") %>% 
    EUtilsGet(type = "efetch", db = "pubmed")
}


### Build function to pull relevant data from S4 into list of lists 

make_list <- function (x) {
  list('PMID' = PMID(x),
       'Authors' = Author(x), 
       'Year' = YearPubmed(x), 
       'Month' = MonthPubmed(x),
       'Day' = DayPubmed(x), 
       'Journal' = Title(x),
       'ISSN' = ISSN(x),
       'PublicationType' = PublicationType(x)) 
}

### Generate dataframe from lists 

extract_data <- function (x) {
  pmap_dfr(x, ~data.frame(
    .y,
    pmid = paste(.x,  collapse = "-"), 
    year = paste(..3, collapse = "-"), 
    month = paste(..4, collapse = "-"), 
    day = paste(..5, collapse = "-"), 
    journal = paste(..6, collapse = "-"), 
    ISSN = paste(..7, collapse = "-"), 
    type = paste(..8, collapse = "-"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}

### Combine scrape, list, and dataframe functions into one process 

gen_df <- function(x) {
  Sys.sleep(5)
  x %>% 
    scrape_pubmed() %>% 
    make_list() %>% 
    extract_data()
}


####################  ACQUIRE DATASET  #################### 

# Searches: 
search_cpg <- c(
"(Guideline[Publication Type]) AND 1990/01/01[PDat]:2020/12/31[PDat] AND 1533-4406[issn]", 
"(Guideline[Publication Type]) AND 1990/01/01[PDat]:2020/12/31[PDat] AND 0028-4793[issn]", 
"(Guideline[Publication Type]) AND 1990/01/01[PDat]:2020/12/31[PDat] AND 1474-547X[issn]", 
"(Guideline[Publication Type]) AND 1990/01/01[PDat]:2020/12/31[PDat] AND 0140-6736[issn]",
"(Guideline[Publication Type]) AND 1990/01/01[PDat]:2020/12/31[PDat] AND 0092-8674[issn]", 
"(Guideline[Publication Type]) AND 1990/01/01[PDat]:2020/12/31[PDat] AND 1091-6490[issn]",
"(Guideline[Publication Type]) AND 1990/01/01[PDat]:2020/12/31[PDat] AND 0027-8424[issn]",
"(Guideline[Publication Type]) AND 1990/01/01[PDat]:2020/12/31[PDat] AND 1538-3598[issn]",
"(Guideline[Publication Type]) AND 1990/01/01[PDat]:2020/12/31[PDat] AND 0098-7484[issn]",
"(Guideline[Publication Type]) AND 1990/01/01[PDat]:2020/12/31[PDat] AND 1527-7755[issn]")

# Run function, create lists using lapply 
list_cpg <- lapply(search_cpg, gen_df)

# Convert list to dataframe
df_cpg <- data.table::rbindlist(list_cpg)
```

Comment: HINT: what does `1:length(x)` produce when `x` is of length 0? This is why you should always use `seq_len()` and `seq_along()`.

Answer (score 0):

OK so a friend send me an obvious answer.  I needed to wrap the loop in a TryCatch function earlier than I was doing.  This code snipped fixed everything, posting in case its helpful for others:

```
gen_df_clean <- function(x) {
  Sys.sleep(5)
  x %>% 
    scrape_pubmed() %>% 
    make_list() %>% 
    extract_data()
}

### Add TryCatch to make scripts more resilient 

gen_df <- function (x) {
  return(tryCatch(gen_df_clean(x), error=function(e) NULL))
}
```